# Is the impedance bus matrix method the same as the Ohmic method in power system fault analysis?

Tags: short-circuit, fault

There are a few methods to do power system fault analysis, like the per-unit method, MVA method, and impedance method (Ohmic method.)

I am doing fault analysis using per unit symmetrical component method by using the impedance bus matrix (Z bus.)

Is that the impedance bus matrix method the same as the Ohmic method?

Can someone please share literature reviews on the Ohmic method?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this, but my understanding is grid-fault [Y-Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_admittance_matrix) or Nodal Admittance Matrix (NAM) is more common.

This reduces the complexity and uses KVL, KCL in the tools rather than matrix inversion of Z-Matrix.